# Minimal Ideals of Corner Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

What are the minimal (one-sided) ideals of a corner ring $eRe$, where $R$ is a unital ring, and $e=e^2\in R$?

If $S$ is a, say, right ideal of $R$, then clearly $eSe$ is a right ideal of $eRe$, but, I don't know whether all right ideals of $eRe$ are of this type.

Thanks in advance, for any cooperation and suggestion!